# How to optimize code for faster execution

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am a beginner.
I'm trying to rewrite a Convolution layer without using TensorFlow or PyTorch, but my code is too slow and memory-intensive. I'm asking this question to seek advice on how to optimize my code. Thank you.

```
class Convolutional:

  def __init__(self, num_neuron, input_shape, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = 1, stride = 1): # đầu vào của lớp Convolution là: số kênh đầu ra của bộ tích chập, hàm kích hoạt, 1 tensor các ảnh (H_ảnh, W_ảnh, channel)
    self.h, self.w, self.input_channel = input_shape
    self.output_channel = num_neuron # số bộ lọc hay số nơ ron lớp hiện tại
    self.padding = padding
    self.kernel_size = kernel_size

    self.h_output = int((self.h - self.kernel_size[0] + 2*self.padding + stride) / stride)
    self.w_output = int((self.w - self.kernel_size[1] + 2*self.padding + stride) / stride)

    self.output_shape = (self.h_output, self.w_output, self.output_channel)
    self.kernel_shape = (self.output_channel, self.kernel_size[0], self.kernel_size[1], self.input_channel)

    self.K = np.random.randn(*self.kernel_shape).astype(np.float32)
    self.B = np.random.randn(*self.output_shape).astype(np.float32)

  def cal_padding(self, input):
    heights, widths, channels = self.h, self.w, self.input_channel
    output = np.zeros((heights+self.padding*2, widths+self.padding*2, channels)).astype(np.float32)
    output[self.padding : self.padding + input.shape[0], self.padding : self.padding + input.shape[1], : ] = input
    return output

  def conv_featuremap(self, input):
    input = input.astype(np.float32)
    input = self.cal_padding(input).astype(np.float32)
    h_kernel, w_kernel = self.kernel_size
    sliding_windows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(input,(h_kernel, w_kernel, self.input_channel)).astype(np.float32)
    featuremap = np.sum(sliding_windows * self.K, axis=(3, 4, 5))
    featuremap += self.B
    return featuremap
  
  def conv_per_img_set(self, input): #input.shape = (số ảnh, H, W, C):
    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    feature_maps = np.array(pool.map(self.conv_featuremap, input))
    return feature_maps

  def forward():
    pass

  def backward():
    pass
```

```
model2 = Convolutional(32,(32,32,3))
start = time.time()
model2.conv_per_img_set(X_train)
end = time.time()
end - start
```

==> 75.3529281616211
And this code take about 15GBs Ram

Comment: I don’t think you’re doing anything wrong. This actually looks like good code. Python is a slow language, computationally intensive operations like convolution are better written in a compiled language.